# Writing permissions issues with the following directories/files Elementor uploads directory

Tags: wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

**Everytime i** want to **update** an specific page on my wordpress site the **page gets frozen** and does not let me use the builder. On Wordpress Dashboard I see this message: Writing **permissions issues** with the following directories/files Elementor uploads directory.

When i check the error logs i find the following:

```
`[error] 14605#14605: *52603 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:
  file_put_contents(/var/www/corvettes2.performancecorvettes.com/public/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-701.css): 
failed to open stream: 
Permission denied in /var/www/corvettes2.performancecorvettes.com/public/
wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/base.php`
```

What i have tried so far:

1. I have make sure **i** have **set** the **correct permissions** on Folders and files (755 Folders & subfolders, 644 files)
2. I **modify the max_input_vars** to 1000 on the **htaccess** file
3. I have **check the nginx conf** file to make sure nothing is odd (still i don't find anything wrong):

;

```
 user  nginx;
 worker_processes  auto;
 worker_rlimit_nofile 20000;
 error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
 pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


  events {
  worker_connections  4096;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}


 http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;

keepalive_requests 100000;
keepalive_timeout  5;
send_timeout 10;

gzip  on;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_vary off;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/x-font-ttf application/font-woff application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php application/x-httpd-fastphp application/x-httpd-eruby image/svg+xml text/javascript text/mathml;
gzip_min_length  1000;
gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
client_max_body_size 20M;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the ownership of the upload directory and it's files. Most likely they're owned by root or another user. If so, use chmod to change it to the nginx user.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me and it is something very simple, it is to go to the wordpress panel > settings > media and you will see a url where the files type "public/sdfs/upload/etc" are being uploaded, you just have to remove that url or directory and you click on the save button, this makes it recognize or search for the new directory, something similar happened to me when I changed my website to another server.

Comment: Thanks for this little nugget. This is for the situation when the website has been moved from a different location. It keeps the old path and it no longer matches once the website is moved to a new server.